# How can I monitor the interactions of an application with dbus?

Tags: logs, monitoring, debugging, d-bus

I have a set of applications, I want to montior any and all interactions of the applications with dbus.

The things I've played with don't seem to have a way of focusing on just one application.

**Addition**

As an example consider two applications  foo and bar that are trying to connect via dbus ( OK the language there is a bit off ). foo tries to setup a server as 'org.gnome.TypingMonitor' but bar tries to connect to 'org.gnome.TypignMonitor'.

I would like to monitor the connection attempts then the data transmitted to make sure handshaking afterwards is working right.

strace might work, but strace is too fine grained. An strace that traces dbus calls instead of system calls would fit the bill.

Comment: I'm unclear how what you're asking for is different than, e.g., `dbus-monitor` with a `sender='whatever',interface='whatever'` (like the example in the man page).

Comment: You are not really asking that are you? So I run the application foo. I want to get a list of all interactions of foo with dbus. How does dbus-monitor get that for me?

Comment: I may well be understanding wrong, but if you ask for messages with a sender of your app or being sent to your app (pretty sure that comma is an or in `dbus-monitor`), doesn't that monitor your app's interaction with dbus?

Comment: There is also the `DBUS_VERBOSE=1` environment variable which might help. But I believe you need a debug build of the dbus libs for that to work. (This sounds better suited to after your addition)